# I'm having trouble understanding this sentence because of 'des', what am I not understanding?

Tags: genitive

Here's the sentence:

> Es war ein strahlender Tag, ***herrlich der Anblick des weit im Süden sich erhebenden Kranzes der Hochalpen***, deren schneebedeckte Gipfel sich kantig in das Blau des Himmels schoben.

To be more specific about what is confusing me: "des weit im Süden"

With my current level of understanding, I feel like a noun should follow 'des'

When I read this part, my brain translates it as: "the far in the south", which doesn't sound right.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Des* refers to *Kranz* here in the genitive: *des Kranzes*.

*Der Kranz erhebt sich weit im Süden* (the rim rises far to the south)
so used as an adjective phrase that's:
*der **weit im Süden sich erhebende** Kranz*